# Schema is required in SQL Server to invoke user-defined functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've always found that when I'm programming in SQL Server, in a database where everything I create is under the `dbo` schema, that I don't need to reference the schema when querying tables or views or executing stored procedures, but I always need to prefix invocations of user-defined functions with `dbo.` or else the parser fails to recognize the name. Why is that?

Comment: The better question is why are you not always schema qualifying when you really should be. [Bad Habits to Kick : Avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) Just because you *can* omit the schema if it's your default schema doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Perhaps the same reason that we don't square-bracket-quote every identifier name. It adds unnecessary clutter in a design that doesn't utilize separate schemas. I agree with the OP - seems like a silly requirement. I wonder if it came out of the SQL standard or other good reason, or if it was just a less than well-thought-out decision made years ago (like interpreting '2023-01-02' dates as year-day-month in DMY environments).

Comment: @TN - there is a perfectly good reason for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is so that it does not clash with (current or future) built in functions.

If you had a function called `dbo.Least` and were allowed to call it as `Least` then you would get a conflict when moving up to SQL Server 2022 as that suddenly has a built in function called `LEAST`.

There is no `sp_` convention for built in function names to indicate an area of names "reserved by Microsoft"

If you `EXEC` the user defined function (rather than `SELECT` it) you can still call it without schema qualification as there is no possibility of ambiguity there.

Answer (score 2):

> I always need to prefix invocations of user-defined functions with dbo. or else the parser fails to recognize the name. Why is that?

No good reason.  It's just a technical limitation of the parser.